# How to track all operation on one object in IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

For example new object allocated, after then it throw to different place, where it is used by a lot of methods. So I want to track all read operations on it to understand in which places this object is used. Something like "go to breakpoint" but "go to next read operation with this object".

Comment: Find Usages has read access operations filter in the results tool window. Is that what you need?

Comment: No, it's not. I need to do that in debug mode, because it's hard to understand what is going on in code. In my case the object which I'm talking about is exception (not standard), and this exception was put in "cause" part of another exception. After that I lose track of the object. There are hundreds place where exception is used so i can't view them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be such a shortcut available with IDEA. I am not aware of such shortcuts in any other IDE either.

Below is a resource with list of all available shortcuts and no such facility is listed.
https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Communities grow with contribution. You're always welcome to submit a request with below link so that it can be considered if feasible.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about seeing where the variable is used (which is what I make from your question), you can just Ctrl-Click on the variable name.

Alternatively, you can right-click on the variable name and click on "Find Usages".

If you want to observe the variable's state and how it changes throughout a debugging session, you can attach a variable "watch" to it.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/debug-tool-window-variables.html for more information on that.

Comment: I'm talking about debug mode because in code it's impossible to understand where object will be used (Code is bad, and I did not write it).  "watch" watch on variable by name and you need visibility to use it. If I have visibility, I will understand everything by reading the code. Object (not a variable with name) escape away from method and goes to meet adventures. Of course everything breaks, but it is unclear where.

Comment: @АлександрМеньшиков then I wish you good luck on your debugging adventure :)